# Gradle build is successful but doesn't generate build folder/ APK file

Tags: android, linux, macos, gradle, apk

I am building an Android app with Gradle using flavours and variants through the commandline. When building the project, it finishes with success but no APK is generated - no build folder is created as well.

What I tried:

- Looking for other locations for the APK file - nothing
- changing Android SDK/Gradle/Java versions

Important to note that when I build it using the same Gradle version, SDK version, java version and same command from the command line on my Mac it does generate the outputs.
The problems occurs on my Linux machine.
I am using gradle wrapper and running the task assemble.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the Linux and macOS android studio configs the same, I mean all dependent paths?

Comment: Hey, I am building through the command line, not with AS

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: `./gradlew assembleMyProject`

Comment: Does `./gradlew assembleDebug -d` yield an apk? If not, anything telling in the logs?

Comment: getting task not found with `assembleDebug`

Comment: @straya any idea?